# Select from MySQL datetime field where the year doesn't matter

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL DateTime field which represent opening times.

I want to write a statement that will allow me to select rows from my table independent of the year supplied (Ex. *-12-17 00:00:00)

Comment: I tried using a WHERE statement with a wildcard or just omitting the year.

The solution below provided by @Aziz worked though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE DAYOFMONTH(datecolumn) = 17
AND MONTH(datecolumn) = 12
```

Reference for [DAYOFMONTH](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofmonth).

Answer (score 0):

You did not say what you wanted to choose by if not the year: Go to the MySQL page and choose the correct functions.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html